# c# return this for generic return type method

Tags: c#

Many of the methods inside my class would `return this;` so that i can call multiple functions within one line. something like `a.method1().method2().method3();` problem arise when i try to make a base class. if I make a method to return type `T` inside the base class, then i can no longer `return this;` since the base class type is not `T`. I can't just make the return type as the base class since there are many more methods that are available on the inherited class that are not in the base class. How can i solve this problem?

Sample code:

```
public class baseClass<T>
{
    public T method1()
    {
        //Do stuffs
        return this;//doesnt work
    }
}

public class inheritedClass:baseClass<inheritedClass>
{
    public inheritedClass method2()
    {
        //Do stuffs
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: what?? post the code.

Comment: @HighCore sample code posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    public T Method1()
    {
        //Do stuffs

        // We are sure any instance of this class is T : BaseClass<T>. 
        // Only exception might be direct instance of BaseClass<T> and that's why we made BaseClass abstract.
        return (T)this;
    }
}  

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass<InheritedClass>
{
    public InheritedClass Method2()
    {
        //Do stuffs
        return this;
    }
}
```

Two things changed. First, we are still casting but doing that in base class. Second we guaranteed this cast to work with where constraint and abstract.

Comment: can't call a.method1().method2() without a cast

Comment: oh....amazing, sorry for the previous comment. Mind explain why it worked? looks like a compiler hack to me

Comment: so basically the abstract keyword is there to prevent ppl from initilizing a BaseClass instance and call Method1 right?

Comment: Yes, in that case it would cause a cast exception.

Comment: BTW, for drawbacks of this pattern you may want to check this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Comment: um..good to know, but i would probably slap the person's face if anyone tries to do dumb things like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Your base class's return type should be the base class itself, not just T.

```
public class baseClass<T>
{
    public baseClass<T> method1()
    {
        //Do stuffs
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: then i can't do a.method1().method2() without a cast

Answer (score 1):

In your base class example, "this" is not a type of "T" but is instead a type of "baseClass{T}". That's why it doesn't work. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but this would probably compile...

```
public class baseClass<T>
{
  public baseClass<T> method1()
  {
    return this;
  }
}

public class inheritedClass : baseClass<inheritedClass>
{
  public baseClass<inheritedClass> method2()
  {
    return this.method1();
  }
}
```

Edit: I understand your question now. This is probably a better overall approach than using inheritance. You can convert the interface to be a generic one if needed...

```
public interface FluentStuff
{
  FluentStuff method1();
  FluentStuff method2();
}

public class MyClass : FluentStuff
{
  public FluentStuff method1()
  {
    return this;
  }

  public FluentStuff method2()
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

But if you insist on using inheritance...

```
public interface FluentStuff
{
  FluentStuff method1();
  FluentStuff method2();
}

public abstract class BaseClass : FluentStuff
{
  public virtual FluentStuff method1()
  {
    return this;
  }

  public abstract FluentStuff method2();
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass, FluentStuff
{
  public override FluentStuff method2()
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

**I highly encourage composition over inheritance.**

Example with generics...

```
public interface FluentStuff<T>
{
  FluentStuff<T> method1();
  FluentStuff<T> method2();
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : FluentStuff<T>
{
  public virtual FluentStuff<T> method1()
  {
    return this;
  }

  public abstract FluentStuff<T> method2();
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass<MyClass>, FluentStuff<MyClass>
{
  public override FluentStuff<MyClass> method2()
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Final example to another question/concern you posted...

```
public class SharedFunctionality
{
  public void DoStuff1()
  {
    // common implementation for do stuff 1
  }

  public void DoStuff2()
  {
    // common implementation for do stuff 2
  }
}

public class MyClass1
{
  private readonly SharedFunctionality sharedFunctionality;

  public MyClass1()
  {
    this.sharedFunctionality = new SharedFunctionality();
  }

  public MyClass1 Method1()
  {
    this.sharedFunctionality.DoStuff1();
    return this;
  }

  public MyClass1 Method2()
  {
    this.sharedFunctionality.DoStuff2();
    return this;
  }
}

public class MyClass2
{
  private readonly SharedFunctionality sharedFunctionality;

  public MyClass2()
  {
    this.sharedFunctionality = new SharedFunctionality();
  }

  public MyClass2 Method1()
  {
    this.sharedFunctionality.DoStuff1();
    return this;
  }

  public MyClass2 Method2()
  {
    this.sharedFunctionality.DoStuff2();
    return this;
  }

  public MyClass2 Method3()
  {
    // do something only this class does
    return this;
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MyClass1 c1 = new MyClass1();
    c1.Method1().Method2();

    MyClass2 c2 = new MyClass2();
    c2.Method1().Method2().Method3();
  }
}
```

Comment: I know why it doesnt compile. What i am trying to accomplish is mentioned in my question, i want to be able to call multiple functions at once. something like a.method1().method2().method3() where method3 could be living inside inhereted class and the return type has to be the inhereted class itself

Comment: the reason why i went for inheritance way is because some methods are just exactly identical across many classes except the return type, and it is redundent to copy/paste them all over the place

Comment: Take a peek at this article, composition provides the same benefits as inheritance but without the restrictions. It makes the code more extensible and maintainable. Especially as base classes inevitably get unwieldy over time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: what if inheritedClass1 has member method3 and inheritedClass2 doesnt?

Comment: you would make both classes (inheritedClass1 and inheritedClass2) both implement the same interface, and only return that interface (not the concrete class). Thus guaranteeing that both classes implement all methods on the interface.

Comment: but i do not want to expose method3 on inheritedClass2 since it doesnt belong to the class. I got like > 20 classes which share 2 functions that are exactly the same and all other ones are pretty much different

Comment: This is literally the best case for composition over inheritance. Just make a new class that does what you're doing in the base class for those two functions. Create an instance of that new class in each class, and call the method on it. Yes, it's a little extra work but it solves your issues. Let me open the compiler and I'll post an example.